# How can I resize divs in order to get same view on all browsers?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to resize three divs from left to right.  The left div and right divs contain contain images and the middle one contains text.  My problem is that the images are being cut off on narrower screens.  Looks ok on 24" monitors.  Anything less, images are cut off on far left and right.  Please see http://www.jandswebsitedesigns.com/family-rev/

I realize there may be a problem with the way the current css is set up.  What I am trying to accomplish is while still seeing the full left and right images, to have the three divs responsively resizing themselves according to screen size, while still aligning with blue div just below it.

```
        <div class= "container" style="display: table; width:  100%; 
            margin-top:  30px; padding: 0;">
            <div class="left-container">
                <div class="bg-img-left"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mid-container">
                <h2 style="margin-bottom:  20px;" 
                     class="headline text-center">Same day services</h2>
                <ul style="margin-top:25px 1; list-style-type:disc">
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Choice of 
                     BIRTH CONTROL METHODS</b> (Condoms, Depo Shot,  
                     <b>Pills</b>, Vaginal Ring, <b>IUD</b>, Foam, Film, 
                     <b>Nexplanon</b>)</li> 
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Health Screenings</b> 
                     (Cholesterol, Anemia, Diabetes, Blood Pressure, sore 
                     throat, BMI, Thyroid)</li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>PAP SMEARS </b>/<b> HPV 
                        Testing</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Breast Exam & Physical 
                      Exams</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>“Painless” STD Testing With
                      Results in 20 Minutes and Treatments</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>IMMUNIZATIONS</b> (HPV, 
                     Meningitis, TDaP, Flu, Hepatitis)</li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Urinary Tract Infection 
                     Testing & Treatment On-Site</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Preventative Primary Health 
                     Care Services</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Colposcopy/Biopsies/Cryo-
                   Therapy</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Pregnancy Testing and 
                    Confirmation</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Infertility Screening</b>
                      </li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Education and Counseling</b>
                     </li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Referrals, Including Medicaid 
                  forms for Pregnant Women and assistance filing Medicaid-
                   HTW applications</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>On-Site Medications</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Pharmacy Services</b></li>
                 <li class="services-style"><b>Breast & Cervical Cancer</b>
                      (Medicaid Applications for persons needing treatments      
                  chemo and radiation)</li>
             </ul>

          </div>
          <div class="right-container">  
                    <div class="bg-img-right"></div>
          </div>
        </div>



.left-container  {
    border:  1px solid black;
    float:  left; 
    width:  25%; 
    margin-top:  35px;  }

.bg-img-left  {
    height: 600px;  
    width:  auto;
        background: url(../img/girl.png) no-repeat center right;
        background-size: cover;  }

.mid-container  {
    border:  1px solid black;
    float:  left; 
    width:  50%; 
    padding:  10px 0 20px 0;  }

.right-container  {
    float:  left; 
    width:  25%; 
    margin-top:  35px;  }

.bg-img-right  {
    border:  1px solid black;
    height: 600px;
    width:  auto;
        background: url(../img/boy.png) no-repeat center left;
        background-size: cover;  }
```

Comment: Have you considered using flexbox or bootstrap to make it responsible? 
I would highly recommend flexbox.

Comment: Is that possible with images.  I read about setting up a flexbox using all text divs and a flexbox using all images, but nothing using a combination of text and image divs

Comment: yeah it shouldn't be an issue. You can just place the image in a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<div class="container" style="display: table; width:  100%; margin-top:  3  0px; padding: 0;">
    <div class="left-container">
            <div class="bg-img-left"><img src="assets/img/girl.png" width="100%"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="mid-container">
    <h2 style="margin-bottom:  20px;" class="headline text-center">Same day services</h2>
    <ul style="margin-top:25px 1; list-style-type:disc">
                    <li class="services-style"><b>Choice of BIRTH CONTROL METHODS</b> (Condoms, Depo Shot, <b>Pills</b>, Vaginal Ring, <b>IUD</b>, Foam, Film, <b>Nexplanon</b>)</li> 
    <li class="services-style"><b>Health Screenings</b> (Cholesterol, Anemia, Diabetes, Blood Pressure, sore throat, BMI, Thyroid)</li>
            <li class="services-style"><b>PAP SMEARS </b>/<b> HPV Testing</b></li>
                    <li class="services-style"><b>Breast Exam &amp; Physical Exams</b></li>
    <li class="services-style"><b>“Painless” STD Testing With Results in 20 Minutes and Treatments</b></li>
                    <li class="services-style"><b>IMMUNIZATIONS</b> (HPV, Meningitis, TDaP, Flu, Hepatitis)</li>
    <li class="services-style"><b>Urinary Tract Infection Testing &amp; Treatment On-Site</b></li>
    <li class="services-style"><b>Preventative Primary Health Care Services</b></li>
    <li class="services-style"><b>Colposcopy/Biopsies/Cryo-Therapy</b></li>
    <li class="services-style"><b>Pregnancy Testing and Confirmation</b></li>
    <li class="services-style"><b>Infertility Screening</b></li>
                    <li class="services-style"><b>Education and Counseling</b></li>
    <li class="services-style"><b>Referrals, Including Medicaid forms for Pregnant Women and assistance filing Medicaid-HTW applications</b></li>
                    <li class="services-style"><b>On-Site Medications</b></li>
                    <li class="services-style"><b>Pharmacy Services</b></li>
                <li class="services-style"><b>Breast &amp; Cervical Cancer</b> (Medicaid Applications for persons needing treatments, chemo and radiation)</li>
</ul>

    </div>

    <div class="right-container">  
            <div class="bg-img-right">
                <img src="assets/img/boy.png" width="100%">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-container {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

.bg-img-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}


.right-container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 35px;
    height: 600px;
}

.bg-img-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I basically took out the background images and used an image tag instead with absolute positioning to align it to the bottom and give it a 100% width of the container. Height is auto.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: @JamesDouglas Please check my answer and let me know if this is what you are looking for? Hope I've understood your question correctly. Thanks.

Comment: thanks so much Gurtej.  It worked. The first time I tried your solution, I had the middle div set at 55%. But once I changed it to 50% - bam!  The person who I am doing it for seemed to only be concerned by the way it looks on 19" monitors and larger.  Anything smaller, there is some space above the images, but not big a deal. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help James! Although my solution may not be the easiest to implement, I am glad that it got the job done :). Please feel free to mark it as an accepted answer if you feel it meets your needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For responsive purposes you are facing THE web problem of heights. The thing here is that your layout is depending of the document height. Flexbox won't help you because you need to specify the height.

One option is using `@media-queries` to avoid text getting too long, keep the original HTML and do:

```
.bg-img-left, .bg-img-right{
  background-size: contain;
  background-position-y: bottom;
  /*background-position-x: right or left according to its position*/
}
```

Other option is deleting `.left-container` and `.right-container` and set both images as backgrounds of `.mid-container` like this:

```
    .mid-container{
       width: 100%; 
       padding: 10px 22.5% 0;
       position:relative;
    }
    .mid-container:before,.mid-container:after{
       content:'';
       position:absolute;
       bottom:0;
       background: transparent no-repeat bottom center 22.5%/100%;
    }
    .mid-container:before{
       left:0;
       background-image:url('../img/girl.png');
    }
    .mid-container:after{
       right:0;
       background-image:url('../img/boy.png');
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry, that did not work.  Can you place more information please?

Comment: I edited my answer but I kept the original one because if you use media-queries is still valid.

Comment: llobet - can you provide more information.  I added <div class="mid-container"> and added the middle text.   but there were no images on left or right.

Comment: Try absolute positioning for your images. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could use bootstrap and to allign your page.
Width of page is devided into 12 and you can choose how big each div should be.

Here is an example from w3schools.com where each column has the width 4:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4, col-md-4, col-lg-4">column 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4, col-md-4, col-lg-4">column 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4, col-md-4, col-lg-4">column 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will not work because I do not need a grid system.  I need the div with an image on both side with a ul list in the middle to resize itself for the smaller screens.